# Выполнение JS в .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, angular

Из клиента мне приходил строка с HTML кодом, которая имеет  тег. Примерно, все выглядит так:

```
<body>
<h1 id="h1-test">Hello world!</h1>

#TableData#

<script>
    const test = document.getElementById("h1-test");
    test.style.color = "red";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

После этого, на беке я формирую некую таблицу, и буду отправлять ее на почту клиенту. Проблема в том, что со стороны клиента может приходить JS. Я хочу на беке применять его к HTML, получать конечную строку (в моем случае, тег h1 со стилем color: red), потом удалять js, и тогда отправлять. Я пытался использовать Jint, но я не могу получать доступ к DOM, и получаю ошибку при выполнение document.getElementBy... Могу ли я обойти
то как-то?

Comment: Какой результат ожидается? При чем здесь C#? Если вопрос, чем выполнять JS, попробуйте поизучать AngleSharp с расширением JS.

Comment: @aepot ожидаю получить просто html с выполненым JS.  У моем примере <h1 id="h1-test" style="color: red">Hello world!</h1>. Поскольку это будет выполняться как Quartz, без участия браузера, мне нужно делать это у C#.

Comment: Сам факт использования DOM намекает, что для выполнения такого кода нужен браузер

Comment: @andreymal да, и в этом вся проблема. Могу ли я сделать какую-нибудь имитацию браузера, или может по другому как-то этот вопрос решить)?

Comment: А зачем имитацию, если можно взять настоящий? Гугл намекает мне, что запустить какой-нибудь Selenium через Quartz вроде не проблема

Comment: `Проблема в том, что со стороны клиента может приходить JS` - а это уже, мне кажется, ваш просчет, ибо как я понял по описанию, у вас есть веб сервер, к которому ваши собственные клиенты подключаются  и что-то шлют.  Почему они шлют UI элементы, а не данные предназначенные для передачи, непонятно...